# How to fix lsp-mode for Elisp?

Tags: init-file, hooks, lsp-mode, lsp

I have this set in my init file:

```lisp
;; build dependency tree for function
(use-package lsp-mode
    :ensure t
    :hook ((clojure-mode . lsp)
           (clojurescript-mode . lsp)
           (prog-mode . lsp))
    :commands lsp)
```

However, I am receiving the following warning when I open my `init.el` file:

```
Warning (lsp-mode): Unable to calculate the languageId for buffer ‘init.el’. Take a look at ‘lsp-language-id-configuration’. The ‘major-mode’ is emacs-lisp-mode Disable showing Disable logging
```

I tried adding:

```lisp
(emacs-lisp-mode . lsp)
```

But, it did not work.

How to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76195792/why-there-is-no-language-server-protocol-for-the-emacs-lisp-language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`emacs-lisp-mode` is derived from `prog-mode` (as so many modes are), so `lsp` was already being started in your Emacs Lisp buffers. The warning simply tells you that `lsp` doesn’t know what programming language the buffer contains, and therefore it cannot look up what server to start. But that’s not a problem, because you don’t want to use LSP at all for Emacs Lisp buffers.

As you are probably aware, LSP is a protocol (or series of predefined messages), which an editor may use to talk to another program called a “Language Server”. This server tells the editor how to behave while editing the document, and allows the user to query information like the filename where a function definition lies. But Emacs already has all of those features for Emacs Lisp code; you don’t need some external program to tell Emacs any of that information.

You shouldn’t activate `lsp` for `prog-mode`, because not every mode derived from `prog-mode` has a Language Server for LSP to talk to. Either that, or you should just ignore the warning. It is just a warning, after all.